# Loading images using a textbox, reading character by character

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, picturebox

I would like to do a program that after entering the number into the textbox and will display the appropriate images. For example, if you type 1 and 2, will show candle and a swan, the program will help in remembering the mnemonic system of numbers. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dane = textBox1.Text;

            if (dane == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No number");
            }
            else
            {
                bool jest_liczba = true;
                try
                {
                    double dane_ok = System.Convert.ToDouble(dane);
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no int");
                    jest_liczba = false;
                }
                if (jest_liczba == true)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            string temp = textBox1.Text; //table
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text = char.ToString(temp[i]);
            }         
            string _katalog = @"c:\obrazki\"; //load picture
            string _typ = ".jpg";
            int _liczba;
            if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out _liczba))
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(_katalog + _liczba + _typ);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program after entering a couple of numbers, displays only one image. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your for..loop is accomplishing.  Just comment it out:

```
// string temp = textBox1.Text; //table
// for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
// {
//   textBox1.Text = char.ToString(temp[i]);
// }
```

That loop currently replaces the TextBox text with the last character of the temp string.

Comment: yep, thats rights. I currently reads only the last character, and I would like all one by one. And that is my question. Please help

Comment: @user2104203 But it looks like you only have one picturebox.  It's not very clear what should happen if you have multiple images but only a single picturebox.

Comment: I added two pictureboxs and I converted my loops. However this had no effect:

`string temp = textBox1.Text; //table

            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)

            {

                textBox1.Text = char.ToString(temp[i]);
                textBox2.Text = char.ToString(temp[i]);
                textBox3.Text = char.ToString(temp[i]);
            }`

Comment: I would like to create something similar to this program in java:[link](http://www.filedropper.com/java)

Comment: @abdicode Your loop is updating *all* of the textboxes to the same value.  You need to check the value of i to determine which textbox you want to update.